# Two "Connect SQL" permissions in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, security, permissions

What is the difference between these two "Connect SQL" permissions in SQL Server 2012?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While I can't be certain because you blanked out the Grantor I think you will find that the rows have a different entry in that column.  It is possible to have multiple entries of a permission in that list if the individual who granted the permission is different.

Comment: The Grantor for the unchecked column (and all other ones) is empty, except the Grantor for the checked column, which is the SA account (which is disabled). Does this simply mean that this account can connect to SQL (through the SA grant) and what does Connect SQL permission without grantor mean in this context? Thanks!

Comment: The grantor really has no effect on the permission.  That account can connect to SQL regardless of the fact that it was granted by 2 different individuals, who they are and whether or not they are active.  My guess is that the grantor column is blank because the login that granted the permission no longer exists.